# Android imageView is lagging when loading image from bitmap

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, imageview, touch-event

I have an imageView that has an touch event that move, rotate, and zoom the imageview. The code works fine, however when I load an image from my gallery instead of from the drawable folder, the touch event is lagging. When I try to move, rotate or zoom in the image, there is a delay and slow.

```
 imgPhoto.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms;
        int startwidth;
        int startheight;
        float dx = 0, dy = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
        float angle = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

            ((BitmapDrawable) view.getDrawable()).setAntiAlias(true);
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    parms = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                    startwidth = parms.width;
                    startheight = parms.height;
                    dx = event.getRawX() - parms.leftMargin;
                    dy = event.getRawY() - parms.topMargin;
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    oldDist = spacing(event);
                    if (oldDist > 10f) {
                        mode = ZOOM;
                    }
                    d = rotation(event);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        x = event.getRawX();
                        y = event.getRawY();
                        parms.leftMargin = (int) (x - dx);
                        parms.topMargin = (int) (y - dy);
                        parms.rightMargin = 0;
                        parms.bottomMargin = 0;
                        parms.rightMargin = parms.leftMargin + (5 * parms.width);
                        parms.bottomMargin = parms.topMargin + (10 * parms.height);
                        view.setLayoutParams(parms);
                    } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                        if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                            newRot = rotation(event);
                            float r = newRot - d;
                            angle = r;
                            x = event.getRawX();
                            y = event.getRawY();
                            float newDist = spacing(event);
                            if (newDist > 10f) {
                                float scale = newDist / oldDist * view.getScaleX();
                                if (scale > 0.6) {
                                    scalediff = scale;
                                    view.setScaleX(scale);
                                    view.setScaleY(scale);

                                }
                            }
                            view.animate().rotationBy(angle).setDuration(0).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();

                            x = event.getRawX();
                            y = event.getRawY();

                            parms.leftMargin = (int) ((x - dx) + scalediff);
                            parms.topMargin = (int) ((y - dy) + scalediff);
                            parms.rightMargin = 0;
                            parms.bottomMargin = 0;
                            parms.rightMargin = parms.leftMargin + (5 * parms.width);
                            parms.bottomMargin = parms.topMargin + (10 * parms.height);
                            view.setLayoutParams(parms);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The works fine when I load the image from the drawable folder like in the following

```
  android:src="@drawable/icon"
```

However, if I try to load an image from the gallery, the touch event that suppose to move, rotate and zoom the image is lagging.

Here's the code that I use to load the image from gallery and set the image as bitmap for the imageView.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

Below is the code that I set the imageview to the image from my phone.

```
         @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        try{
            InputStream imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            imgPhoto.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the same image file in drawable and selected from gallery?

Comment: no, different images. But I tried with the same image, and it behaves the same way. And I'm getting "Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread" when I move, rotate, and zoom the image from gallery.

Comment: We cannot see how you load that image from drawable.

Comment: Actually I found out the problem. It was because the image I load from gallery is 3MB whereas the one I have in the drawable folder is much smaller. Thank you.